# I want to select specific text from textarea and make it bold, italic or make an hyperlink in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using textarea for making an editor and wanna implement bold, italic or hyperlink to a selected text.  Right now, if I am making it bold or italic, the effect is in entire box.  I wanna restrict it and keep it to selected text only.  I am able to get the selected text from the textarea, I am not able to make it bold or italic or put a link on the selected task as document.execCommand doesn't work in reactjs.

I am getting the selected text from textarea through getSelectionTxt() function but with this text_to_hyperlink it is replacing the entire text with anchor tags and url.

I want to have that link to be associated with the selected tags.  I am invoking this text_to_hyperlink with a button.

```
text_to_hyperlink=()=> {
  var text_entry = document.getElementById('textArea');
  var text_selected = this.getSelectionTxt();
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  text_entry.value = '<a href="' + url + '">' + text_selected + '</a>' ;
}    
getSelectionTxt =() => {
   var text = "";
   var activeEl = document.activeElement;
   if (activeEl == "textarea") {
       text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
   } else if (window.getSelection) {
       text = window.getSelection().toString();
   }
   var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
   return text;
}

<textarea
          id="textArea"
          contenteditable="true"
          rows="10"
          value={this.state.value}
          onClick={this.getSelectionTxt}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

Comment: You are essentially trying to recreate TinyMCE. That's a pretty big task, much to big for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: In someways yes, but i just want to make the selected text bold and put an hyperlink on it.   I am getting the selected text, I am not getting how to make it bold and put a link on it.

Comment: You can't make part of a textarea's text bold, or a link. A textarea can only contain plain text. You can allow the user to conveniently create HTML source code by inserting tags into the text, but if you want a WYSIWYG editor you need to find another solution.

Comment: I recommend looking at some markdown editors to give you an idea on how to create the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a `textarea` element: they support plaintext only, and not HTML. You will have to use a different element with `contenteditable="true"`. I prefer `div`, but others work as well.

Comment: contenteditable div doesn't support onChange prop. So it's difficult to control the element. Is there any alternative which does support onChange??

Answer (score 0):

A `textarea` element cannot render HTML. You could either use a WYSIWYG editor compatible with React like one of these:

1) Medium-Editor - https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor

2) Draft.js - https://draftjs.org/

or use a `<div>` with `contentEditable=true` and render HTML inside of it.